# PNG or PDF (or EPS)

Tags: graphics, eps, standalone, matlab, png

Is there a preferred format between `PNG, PDF, or EPS` for use with `pdflatex`, particularly in terms of compile speed?

If I understand, `pdflatex` must convert each `PNG`/`EPS` file to a `PDF` file with each compile.  Would it be quicker to convert to `PDF` files prior to compiling?

Is the `standalone` package a preferred method to accomplish this?

Also, if anyone is familiar with Mathworks' Simulink and Stateflow, is it preferred to use the `Matlab` commands `print` and `sfprint` to create `PNG` or `EPS` snapshots of systems, with the intent to use them with `pdflatex`.

Comment: png is a bitmap format so fine for images but avoid using it for line drawings such matlab plots for which a scalable format such as eps or (for pdflatex) pdf is much preferred.

Comment: PNG can be used directly. EPS must be converted but they don't have to be re-converted each time, as far as I know. So compilation might take a little longer, but you won't spend the time pre-converting so it will probably be slower overall. (But this is just an *a priori* guess, and such guesses are never correct!)

Comment: I haven't delved into the (massive) spec for PDF, but I'm almost certain it is simpler (i.e. faster) to include a PDF in another. If you're going for raw compile speed, I'd go with PDF.

Comment: Alternatively, save the raw data to file and use pgfplots to create graphs (or tikz more generally)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build on David Carlisle's comment, there's a judgement call to make for plots with PNG (raster) vs PDF (vector). If you have a scatter plot with thousands of data points for example, there comes a point where vector graphics can make the resulting PDF document (alone or compiled into a LaTeX-produced document) large, slow and unresponsive. In such cases I output to PNG (using R and ggplot2 rather than Matlab, but the principle is the same).

I would suspect that PDF is faster than EPS but I imagine on a modern machine that the difference in compile time would be minimal it wouldn't be worth optimising.

Comment: Another (but more workintensiv) solution of your scatter plot problem is, to export it from matlab, R or whatever in two formats, both PNG and PDF. These two images can than be combined for example with inkscape, so that the scatter points are taken from the raster image but overlaid with axis etc. from the vector image.

Comment: @samcarter What about Simulink system snapshots? I use the `print` function to take a snapshot of each subsystem in a large model. I've typically printed to `png` files. I'm wondering if it is worth converting them all to `pdf` files, as each `png` file takes a couple seconds to compile.

Comment: @kando Sorry, I am not familiar with Simulink.

Comment: To build on this answer, could you provide an image example of a case in which one would definitely want to use raster and a case in which one would definitely want to use vector?